# Are recompiled-from-source classes in Spark jars breaking sbt's merge?

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

Attempting to create a fat jar with sbt gives an error like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
C:\Users\db\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-network-common_2.10\jars\spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.3.jar:com/google/common/base/Function.class
C:\Users\db\.ivy2\cache\com.google.guava\guava\bundles\guava-14.0.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Function.class
```

There are many classes, this is just one for the sake of example. Guava 14.0.1 is the version in play for Function.class in both jars:

```
[info]  +-com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1
...
[info]  | | +-com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1
```

That means sbt/ivy won't pick one as the newer version, but the sizes and dates are different in the jars, which presumably leads to the error above:

```
$ jar tvf /c/Users/db/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.10/jars/spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.3.jar | grep "com/google/common/base/Function.class"
   549 Wed Nov 02 16:03:20 CDT 2016 com/google/common/base/Function.class

$ jar tvf /c/Users/db/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-14.0.1.jar  | grep "com/google/common/base/Function.class"
   543 Thu Mar 14 19:56:52 CDT 2013 com/google/common/base/Function.class
```

It appears that Apache is re-compiling `Function.class` from source rather than including the class as originally compiled.
Is that a correct understanding of what's happening here? Now, it's possible to exclude the re-compiled classes using sbt, but is there
a way to build the jar without explicitly excluding each jar containing re-compiled source by name? Excluding the jars explicitly leads to something
along the lines of the snippet below, which makes it seem that I'm going down a wrong path here:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.3"
  excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.twitter"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.spark", name = "spark-network-common_2.10"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.hadoop", name = "hadoop-client"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.hadoop", name = "hadoop-hdfs"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.tachyonproject", name = "tachyon-client"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "commons-beanutils", name = "commons-beanutils"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "commons-collections", name = "commons-collections"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.hadoop", name = "hadoop-yarn-api"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.hadoop", name = "hadoop-yarn-common"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.curator", name = "curator-recipes")
  )
,
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-network-common" % "1.6.3" exclude("com.google.guava", "guava"),
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.6.3",
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2",
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0" exclude("com.google.guava", "guava"),
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0.1",
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.11",
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" % "3.2.11",
libraryDependencies += "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "4.1.1",
libraryDependencies += "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.10",
```

If that's the wrong path, what's a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If that's the wrong path, what's a cleaner way?

The cleaner way is to not package `spark-core` at all, it's available to you when you install Spark on your target machines and will be available to your applications at runtime (you can usually find them under the `/usr/lib/spark/jars`).

You should mark these spark dependencies as `% provided`. This should help you avoid many of the conflicts inflicted by packing these jars.

Comment: That's what I'm doing for the application that runs under Spark in the cloud. Some of that same code is used as part of a GUI. There's nothing provided there by a container. Maybe that points to a better way to build the jar for the GUI?

Comment: @DonBranson I see. I would definitely not recommend packing Spark as part of any uber jar, it'll lead you to dependency hell as Spark is pretty massive. Instead, I'd make sure the container has these dependencies provided by some configuration management which is responsible to unpack the Spark jars there.

Comment: It's a hot dependency mess, for sure. There's no container for the GUI. I need to build a standalone that I can share with non-developers. Is there a way to do that? Maybe I need to make a zip with all the jars, and a script to add them all to a classpath.

Comment: @DonBranson That definitely sounds like a better path to take.

Comment: Thanks, trying that.

Comment: That does work. I end up with over 50 jars to include, which isn't great. But that's step one. Step two, make it beautiful .;)